# If water level is rising on its own on oil heating unit instead of going down, could I have a leak? Or something worse?

Tags: hvac

If water level is rising instead of lowering on oil heater unit, is there a leak? Could something worse happen. Oil man had to drain water to lower water, and said to watch it to make sure it doesn't rise again. Any answers much appreciated ☺️

Answer (score 1):

The two most common causes are:

1. Defective auto-fill valve (most common in steam systems).

   The fill valve is similar to a toilet fill valve where a float ball
   raises or lowers with the level of the water maintaining correct
   levels.
2. Leaking heating coil.

   Also, a leaking coil within a tank-less or indirect domestic water
   heater. The coil sits in the furnace and if it leaks, municipal
   water collects within the furnace, causing an overfilled condition.

Comment: Thank you☺️ Your explanation was very easy to understand. Enjoy your day and family.